# How to match all lines that do not start with ' "xxxx"' in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have the following text:

```
    {

        "generatedDate": "Wed 2015.05.06 at 09:29:22 AM EDT",
        "keyCode": "1234",
        "id": "84848884",
        "configuration": "test",
        "_version_": 3218761876324876321

    },
    {

        "generatedDate": "Wed 2015.05.06 at 09:29:22 AM EDT",
        "keyCode": "1234",
        "id": "84848884",
        "configuration": "test",
        "_version_": 3218761876324876321

    }
```

How do I match all lines except the ones that start with "keyCode" (with the quotes)? Note - there are several spaces and/or tabs in front of the "keyCode"

Comment: There's a simillar problem answered here
http://superuser.com/questions/290247/how-to-delete-all-line-except-lines-containing-a-word-i-need

Comment: you mean you want everything except key code ?if yes
You can bookmark : keyword .. then  select unbookmarked .. such way all eycode will be remove .. if no what do u want exaclty ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a negative lookahead:

```
^(?!\s*"keyCode").*
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/VQ074M0X5r).

Comment: Sorry - had to wait 10 minutes, then i forgot! accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried this :

```
^(?![ \t]*"keyCode":.*).*$
```

With success with your JSON file